# how to pass user name dynamicaly?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, session, redux

---

### hi , i have this kind of problem .. in my code i should pass the User name dynamicaly

here is my DashBoard wher i should  pass the user name like "welcome ,UserName"

```
 const Dashboard = ({logoutUser, user}) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  console.log("Dashboard user", user)

  //here in console i can see the username that i pass   
    return (
    
            <StyledFromArea bg={colors.dark2}>
                <StyledTitle size={65}>Welcome : {user.name } 
                   { console.log("user.name", user.name)}  
                </StyledTitle>
                { // but here in console returning undefined , why? }
                <Userinfo/>
                <ButtonGroup>
                    <StyledButton to="#" onClick={() => logoutUser(history)}>Logout</StyledButton>
                </ButtonGroup>
            </StyledFromArea>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = ({session}) => ({
    user: session.user,
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {logoutUser})(Dashboard)

//in logout acton i just deleting the sessionService.deleteSession()
//sessionService.deleteUser() and redirect to the  home page
```

Comment: `console.log` returns undefined

Comment: i just try to console for understanding why i can't print the name ,,,and discover that my user.name is undefined

Comment: if user.name is coming back undefined then the issue is probably more to do with the prop that is being passed in. Are you sure that the parent component is getting user

Comment: i think yes ,,,,
here is my code ,,,,maybe i'm doing something wrong ?
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-butterfly-hyh42

Comment: How is the `user` property defined? I'm guessing you need to use `useEffect()` or similar.

Comment: By your own comments it sounds as though the username is attached to user, not user.name. 

However if user.name is returning in the console later this is likely a rendering issue. 

Render -> user.name is undefined leading to your code breaking

Then once user.name is loaded it's then been logged out.

Comment: Looking at your sandbox you arent passing and props down to your components so thats why it is undefined

Comment: @RichardHpa should i pass props from action ?,i'm really sorry for those kind of questions i'm new in frontend(redux),and can't understand how to pass

Comment: Yes you should. Your declaring dashboard like this  `const Dashboard = ({logoutUser, user}) => {` so you are expecting 2 props, `logoutUser` and `user`. but in your `App.js` file when you use `<Dashboard />`, there are no props being passed to it. I would recommend going back and understanding how React uses props before you do something complicated like authentication.

Comment: thank you, i'll go and read and try to understand React Props one more time,